# what is the sequence following in the given question

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

given value of b i.e, [0,b]

n is number indicating that how many times sequence generated . The sequence is generated in the following way

1)first write all the number from [0,b]
2) now make pairs from starting 0 like [0,1),[2,3),[4,5).....last pair
   i)if length of the sequence  is odd the last pair  [b,b+1)
3) when the new sequence is generated go back to step 2 and make pairs and again generate the new sequence until the sequence contains only value zero

when b=1

1->   0,1,
2->   0, ,

for b =3

1->   0,1,2,3
2->   0, ,2
3->   0,1
4->   0

for b=4

1->   0,1,2,3,4,
2->   0, ,2, ,4,
3->   0,1, , ,4,
4->   0, , , ,4,
5->   0,1,2,3, ,
6->   0, ,2, , ,
7->   0,1, , , ,
8->   0, , , , ,

for b=5

1->   0,1,2,3,4,5,
2->   0, ,2, ,4, ,
3->   0,1, , ,4, ,
4->   0, , , ,4, ,
5->   0,1,2,3, , ,
6->   0, ,2, , , ,
7->   0,1, , , , ,
8->   0, , , , , ,

when b=18

1->   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,
2->   0, ,2, ,4, ,6, ,8, ,10,  ,12,  ,14,  ,16,  ,18,
3->   0,1, , ,4,5, , ,8,9,  ,  ,12,13,  ,  ,16,17,  ,
4->   0, , , ,4, , , ,8, ,  ,  ,12,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
5->   0,1,2,3, , , , ,8,9,10,11,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
6->   0, ,2, , , , , ,8, ,10,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
7->   0,1, , , , , , ,8,9,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
8->   0, , , , , , , ,8, ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
9->   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
10->  0, ,2, ,4, ,6, , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
11->  0,1, , ,4,5, , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
12->  0, , , ,4, , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
13->  0,1,2,3, , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
14->  0, ,2, , , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
15->  0,1, , , , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
16->  0, , , , , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,16,  ,  ,
17->  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,  ,  ,  ,
18->  0, ,2, ,4, ,6, ,8, ,10,  ,12,  ,14,  ,  ,  ,  ,
19->  0,1, , ,4,5, , ,8,9,  ,  ,12,13,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
20->  0, , , ,4, , , ,8, ,  ,  ,12,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
21->  0,1,2,3, , , , ,8,9,10,11,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
22->  0, ,2, , , , , ,8, ,10,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
23->  0,1, , , , , , ,8,9,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
24->  0, , , , , , , ,8, ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
25->  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
26->  0, ,2, ,4, ,6, , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
27->  0,1, , ,4,5, , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
28->  0, , , ,4, , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
29->  0,1,2,3, , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
30->  0, ,2, , , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
31->  0,1, , , , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,
32->  0, , , , , , , , , ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,

now i want to derive a formula so that i will get the sequence for the given value of n and b. By the way i want to calculate the xor value of sequence for given n and b

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Do you have one sequence here or many?  What do you mean by range?  Edit your post to make it clear what the inputs are and what are the outputs.

Comment: Without any background, this is just a big amount of numbers and I don't see how one should immediately get the system. Did you try for smaller ranges? Maybe not 18 but start with 2, then 3, 4, etc. Here, you might see a system and than you can verify with this big list that it is the right one.

Comment: when the value of range is given for n=1 , write down all the number from [0,range] ,then form pairs in the current sequence forms another sequence in the following way [first number in pair, second number in pair)

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Do not put vital information in comments.  Also, I have no idea what your comment means.  Is $n$ the range or is $n$ some other parameter?  If you are generating the list of sequences by some code, why not include the code or, better, write out pseudocode to explain the procedure.

Comment: i added some more examples for better understanding

Comment: Once again, please edit your post for clarity.  Do not put vital information in the comments.  And saying $n$ is "some parameter" is not helpful.  How is the parameter used?

Comment: sorry sir , iam poor in english . once again i will modify the question

Comment: Sorry, this simply isn't clear at all.  I think you have a simple way of generating this array of numbers but without explanation your readers are just forced to make a lot of guesses.  Why do that?  Just explain, clearly and precisely, what the inputs are, what the output is, and what manipulations are performed to get from input to output.

Comment: i wrote with proper indentation but that is not coming

Comment: still any modifications are needed sir ?@lulu

Comment: I am not getting it, sorry.  If $b=1$ then it seems to me that your rule just generates $\{0,1\}$ forever.  I think someone else might be able to sort out what you mean, but I really can't.  Good luck.

Comment: i think now it is clear to understand

Comment: just to make sure i understood what you are asking , for $b=7$ could you verify that the sequences are :

$n=1$ => $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$  ,,,,,,,

$n=2$ => $0,,2,,4,,6,$ ,,,,,,,,,

$n=3$ => $0,1,,,4,5,,$ ,,,,,,,,,

$n=4$ => $0,,,,4,,,$ ,,,,,,,,,

$n=5$ => $0,1,2,3,,,,$ ,,,,,,,,,,,

$\cdots$ the same as for $b=3$ from here.

Comment: yes the sequence is same for 3 and 7 after some extent. And i want to generate the sequence directly for given value of $b$ and $n$

Comment: O.K., since you confirmed that i could tell you this, i can easily prove that when $n=2^k$ for some integer $k$ then the sequence will contain only the numbers that are  divisible by $2^k$ and less than $b$, could you check for example when $n=16$ and $b=50$ the only numbers in the sequence will be $0,16,32,48$.

Comment: Yes , exactly the sequence u metioned is correct

Comment: Good, i think about more general way to generate the sequence given $n$ and $b$ but it may take a while, back to you when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of work, i managed to understand what happens in the sequences.

If we called power of $2$ "iceberg" then they need $2^k$ operation(sequences) to all other numbers to "melt down" and they are on the verge of "melting", resulting to produce all numbers less than them.

Now i will give you a pseudo-algorithm that runs on $O( b\ln n)$ time instead of $O(b n)$ for producing the next sequence from the previous(i am assuming you use this algorithm to produce the sequences).

Given $n$ and $b$ ,

**Note: if $n=1$ at any time then we add the candidates list to the final and we are done :)**

1) Let $2^k$ be the smallest number bigger than $n$ and include in list all numbers that are divisible by $2^k$ and less or equal to $b$, and we add all number from $1$ to $b$ as candidates.

**Note : as a number is added to the final list its removed from candidates list**

2) Let $n' = n-2^m$ such that $2^m$ is the biggest number smaller or equal to $n$ and we leave all candidates that are divisible by $2^m$ but not by $2^{m+1}$  and remove the rest.

3) If $n'=0$ add the numbers from step $2$ to the list and we are done :)

**Note : add also $0$, but in every other step we are not dealing with $0$.**

4) If $n'>0$ then every number from step $2$ that is divisible by $2^m$ remove it in write instead all the numbers in the interval that is at least $1$ less than the number and at most $2^m-1$ less than the number.

5) Let $n=n'$ and return to step $2$.

An Example :

Trying the algorithm for $n=37,b=101$

1) from step $1$ we get that $64>37$ so we add 64 to the list and the list now contains $\{64\}$.

2) from step $2$ we get that $37>32$ so $n'=37-32=5$ and $2^m=32$, now we leave all number in the interval [1,101] that are divisible by $32$ but not divisible by $64$ which are $32,96$.

4) $n'=5>0$ so we remove $32$ and write all number from $1$ to $31$ and from $65$ till $95$ as candidates.

5) $n=5$ now and we repeat from step $2$.

2) $5>4$ so $n'=5-4=1$ and $2^m=4$ ,now we remove all candidates that are not divisible by $4$ , we are left with $4,8,12,16,20,24,28,68,72,76,80,84,88,92$

4) $n'=1>0$ so we remove all numbers divisible strictly be $4$ (meaning divisible by $4$ but not by $8$) and replace them with the same number -[1,3]

For example $4$ is removed and replaced with $1,2,3$ , $12$ is removed and replaced with $9,10,11$, so we are left with $1,2,3,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,27,65,66,67,72,73,74,75,80,81,82,83,88,89,90,91$.

5) $n=1$ and we are back to $2$ is special case and we add the candidates to the final list and we are done :)

So the final list will be $\{0,1,2,3,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,27,64,65,66,67,72,73,74,75,80,81,82,83,88,89,90,91\}$.

I tried my best to simplify it for a CS student, also i shifted it from a linear algorithm to logarithmic in the run time, so its really fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ahmad

Comment: you are welcome, did you understand it and is it helpful ?

Comment: also if you want to implement this algorithm, i suggest you use Stacks rather than arrays since the former are dynamic and the latter are static.

Comment: Yes I understood after some time , and it is very helpful